# Assign Numeric Value as a Variable for an Equation Based on Input From Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a workbook that has various "calculators" for weld engineering on each sheet. For one of the calculators the equation is based on material density but rather than have the user input the correct value I want to use a combobox with a list of materials which I can then have the macro use assign the correct density value to in the equation.

I haven't used combobox before, so I honestly have no idea how to accomplish this step and my searches haven't yielded anything useful thus far.

I have the combobox populating the materials when the workbook opens (located in "ThisWorkbook") and once I get to the point where I can assign, say .2854 to "Steel" in the macro for the sheet ("Deposited Weight") I can get the rest.

```
Sub Workbook_open()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Deposited Weight").ComboBox1
    .AddItem "Steel"
    .AddItem "Stainless"
    .AddItem "Aluminum"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You could use a lookup table for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution that allowed me to keep everything in the macro rather than building a table somewhere on the worksheet. I really want to keep the calculator sheets clean.

I found another question where the value of the combobox was needed as a string which turned on a lightbulb, I could use a couple if-then statements to define different values to a single variable based on the input from the combobox.

It's not the most efficient solution but for just 3 selectable options in the drop down it works. (Combobox name was changed from "ComboBox1" to "CboMaterials")

```
Dim MatType as String
MatType = Me.CboMaterials.Text

If MatType = "Steel" Then
    Dens = 0.2854
End If

If MatType = "Stainless" Then
    Dens = 0.2901
End If

If MatType = "Aluminum" Then
    Dens = 0.0975
End If
```

Comment: If you have even the remotest possibility of adding to or editing this data, then use a lookup table.  Always build around the idea that you aren't always going to be around,  so someone has to maintain this file.  If you suddenly become rich and decide that life in Aruba sounds more attractive than where you currently live, then someone else is going to have to support this tool.  Lookup tables make this process vastly simpler.  So  if your successor has to add Titanium to your calculator, then all they have to is add a record to a lookup table and everything flows with no editing code needed

Answer (score 0):

Consider using ComboBox properties instead of code. May be achievable without coding.

Populating both material and value columns on ComboBox improves the user experience.

| Properties | Value | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ColumnCount | 2 | specify the number of columns displayed in combobox |
| BoundColumn | 2 | use the 2nd column use as the value of the combobox |
| LinkedCell | A1 | update cell A1 with combobox's value |
| ListFillRange | $A$15:$B$18 | sets the worksheet range used to fill the combobox |

[image]

Please refer to Microsoft document:

[ControlFormat.LinkedCell property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.controlformat.linkedcell?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

[ControlFormat.ListFillRange property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.controlformat.listfillrange?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

---

If your goal is to retrieve the selected value from the combobox in VBA code, you can use the Change event

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    MsgBox "Selection is " & Me.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```